# salesforce scratch org push showing error

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, scratch-org

when I am trying to push my code on scratch org its showing error:

```
public with sharing class HospitalController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static string getAllHospitals(){
        try {
            return [SELECT Hospital_Name__c, Branch__c, Address__c FROM Hospital__c 
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

following error showing :

> Error HospitalController Invalid type: Schema.Hospital__c (14:20)
> Error showHospitals      Unable to find Apex action class referenced as 'HospitalController'.

Comment: Sounds like you need to push your `Hospital__c` SObject (and its fields) to your scratch org along with this code.

Comment: @DerekF
can u please guide me here.
how to push custom object and custom object fields to scratch org.

Comment: You will needs to have the `Hospital__c` custom object defined in the `objects` folder that `is located in the same folder as the `classes` folder.

Comment: If you're not able to retrieve the Hospital__c object for some reason(s) (perhaps it was in a scratch org which has now expired), you can of course just create a new custom object in your scratch org and add those custom fields too, and then push your code and it'll compile. Or alternatively, just change Hospital__c to Account and change the custom fields to some standard Account fields; and that'll compile too.

Comment: Do I have to create custom objects and it's fields in scratch org explicitly, I mean we can push our code, custom objects, fields directly from vs code using sfdx command sfdx force:source:push -f, using this to push then why do we need to create objects by ourselves in scratch org ?,. what if I have somewhat 400 objects do I need to create all 400 one by one ??